# Laplace Transform Derivative (In context of differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solve

$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
y''+5y'+6y=3e^{4t}\\ y(0)=1\\ y'(0)=-1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$$

I solved it using Laplace Transforms.

However, the transform of derivatives only uses $y(0)$, and not $y(1)$ or $y(-2)$.

What if the IVP gave me $y(5)$ and $y'(5)$ instead? My solution would be in terms of $y(0)$.

Comment: I think you need translation arguments - but don't quote me on that. That is, something like $u(t) = y(t-h)$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson oh waittttt its cuz of the integration bounds on the laplace transform its 0 to infinity, so when you do the lower bound OHHhHhHh

so if i used a u substitution like u(t)=y(t-h), i could shift up/down the lower bound which gives me the thingy